# This app could not be installed on iOS simulator, Could not hardlink copy

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xcode11.3

I've noticed an odd issue that recently happened with my simulator. Whenever I change my `CFBundleShortVersionString` value from 2019.12 to 2020.1 this issue happens, if I put it back to 2019.12 or do 2019.13, it works just fine.

I get this message:

> This app could not be installed at this time, Could not hardlink copy

Doesn't matter what version or device I set it to either, just super random and seems to have been since I've upgraded to XCode 11.3

I can clear the app and it works, but that's mega annoying and I'd prefer to not do that.

this what those values look like:

```xml
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>2020.1</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>40</string>
```

Comment: Hi , which is the version of  Visual Studio ?

Comment: Visual Studio For Mac 2019

Comment: The latest version ? I also tried in my local site , it shows no problem . Could you share how modify it in your project ?

Comment: updated the question for you @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Could you create a new solution and see if you can replicate it there?

Comment: @Eman Okey , I have checked the latest version of VS for Mac(8.4) and VS (16.4.2) . They all work after modifying the `CFBundleShortVersionString` to `2020.1` without cleaning . You can reboot mac and have a try with new solution to check it .

Comment: I might try reinstalling VS for Mac and see if that works, I've had to do that once before

Comment: @Eman Okey, if good news , remember to share here .

Comment: I did make a new app and that one is working fine so wondering if something else is wrong with my info.plist file

Comment: I figured out my problem, I had a bad entry in my InfoPList.strings file, removed it and it works now

Comment: @Eman Glad find the reason ! You can share it in answer . Then other people will see it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I had a bad entry in my InfoPList.strings file, I removed it and it works now. I removed an entry for the version (which I forgot I did that) and the app name for those interested in knowing what I removed.